# Upgraded to Ruby 1.9.3-p374, now default Rails port is 5000. How to change back?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreman

I just upgraded to Ruby 1.9.3-p374 on my development machine. Now, when I start Rails with `foreman start`, it uses port 5000.

Here is my Procfile:

```
web: bundle exec rails server thin -p $PORT -e $RACK_ENV
```

My .env:

```
RACK_ENV=development
PORT=3000
```

Why is it giving me port 5000, and how can I change it back?

Comment: Sounds like your .env file is not being read. Are you in the same directory as the .env file? Foreman uses 5000 as the default port. Does it work on 3000 if you supply that in your Procfile?

Comment: The .env and the Procfile are in the same directory. If I put 3000 in my Procfile, it works fine.

Comment: What version of Foreman are you using?

Comment: It was using the version installed under my old ruby directory- I hadn't installed it again since upgrading, I'd forgotten it wasn't in my gemfile. Installing it again worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was using the version installed under my old ruby directory- I hadn't installed it again since upgrading, I'd forgotten it wasn't in my gemfile. Installing it again worked.